# installing ubuntu 13.04 along side window 7 64 bit

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, 64-bit

I have a 64 bit computer with windows OS. Here are my specifications:

- core i3 processor
- 4 gb ram
- nvdia ge210
- hard disk with 680 gb memory

In my windows installation I have C: drive with 104 gb, D: drive with 246gb and E: drive with 246gb memory. My dvd rom is in f: drive.

I want to install ubuntu 13.04 64 bit along side windows 7. So i burned the ubuntu 64 bit iso image onto a dvd and restarted the computer. but in the choice for installations, there is no option to select installing ubuntu along side windows. There is an option to install ubuntu inside windows instead. There are other options as well.
What should I do to get the option to install ubuntu along side windows. I think the problem is with the number of drives in windows. Please tell me how should I make a partition in windows 7 to install ubuntu.
Thanks a lot..

Comment: With a hidden system/restore partition, you've reached your max of 4 primary partitions for msdos partition tables. You need to backup E: (the last one on disk), delete it, create an Extended partition, then you can add logical partitions for your linux install, minimum a swap and root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Ubuntu is not seeing Windows.

Follow these instructions to fix the problem:

1. Boot into BIOS
2. Set the SATA mode to IDE
3. Set the SATA3 mode to AHCI
4. Install. You will need to change these settings back when you boot into Windows and vice versa, as Windows cannot boot with these settings.
5. It is likely the bootloader will not show up, but that can be fixed easily by first typing `sudo fdisk -l` in a Terminal
6. Then, run `sudo mount /dev/STEP_5_OUTPUT /mnt && sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sda`

Now you should be able to boot, but be sure to revert the changes to BIOS to boot Windows and vice versa